# How can i use a string to reference a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings:

```
arr = ["bar","baz"]
```

and I have a few variables:

```
var bar = 'Hello';
var baz = 'bye';
```

using the array, how can I ouput:

```
hello
bye
```

I know how to loop, but, how can i use a string to refence a variable?

Comment: `var arr = new Array(); arr["somevalue"] = "Hello"; var bar = arr["somevalue"];`

Comment: @DLeh no he means that he wants to access a variable by computing its name. That's not generally possible in JavaScript, though it *is* possible to access object properties via computed names (using the `[ ]` operator), and global variables are object properties (of the global object, `window` in a browser).

Comment: @DLeh Why would you `new` up an `Array` specifically, then use it as an associative container? Just use an object (or `Map`, where available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables are global, you can access them by name using the property index of the `window` element:

```js
arr = ["bar","baz"]

var bar = 'Hello';
var baz = 'bye';

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  alert(window[item]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to store the variables as properties within an object, and reference them that way:

```
var data = {
    bar: "Hello",
    baz: "Bye"
};

arr.forEach((key) => doStuff(data[key]));
```

Failing that, if you have access to some other scope (perhaps `this` during a method call), you can keep the variable as properties on the scope.

If you don't have any other scope available and no good options, all global variables are attached to the `self` (or `window`, when available) scope, so you can use the same sort of `window[key]` access.